# Load the Audio file in exernal memory using stm32

Tags: stm32, flash-memory, map-files, hex-file

I want to move audio files in bin format to external flash. I used `incbin` for this. The audio files were present in `.map` file but in `.hex` file these data were missing.

Give me a solution for this issue.

Comment: Not sure that "Give me a solution for this issue" will convince many people to help you...

Comment: Give me more information: the map file, the hex file, how you generate it, etc...